# Change major mode from fundamental to shell in emacs

Tags: emacs, mode

Surprisingly file **.bashrc_custom** has *Fundamental* mode even though files **.bashrc** and **.bash_profile** in the same directory have *(Shell-script[bash])*.

How can I configure major mode for .bashrc_custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your Emacs init file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.bashrc_custom\\'" . sh-mode))
```

Note possibly directory local variables are not questioned here, it's ruled by a list reading strings resp. regular expressions for matching file-names.